# Nopcommerce 4.2 - How to get Category for _ProductBox Partial View

Tags: c#, sql-server, dependency-injection, nopcommerce, .net-core-2.2

I added to ProductModelFactory.cs this code ProductCategories = product.ProductCategories.ToList()

```
public virtual IEnumerable<ProductOverviewModel> PrepareProductOverviewModels(IEnumerable<Product> products,
            bool preparePriceModel = true, bool preparePictureModel = true,
            int? productThumbPictureSize = null, bool prepareSpecificationAttributes = false,
            bool forceRedirectionAfterAddingToCart = false)
        {
            if (products == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(products));

            var models = new List<ProductOverviewModel>();
            foreach (var product in products)
            {
                var model = new ProductOverviewModel
                {
                    Id = product.Id,
                    Name = _localizationService.GetLocalized(product, x => x.Name),
                    ShortDescription = _localizationService.GetLocalized(product, x => x.ShortDescription),
                    FullDescription = _localizationService.GetLocalized(product, x => x.FullDescription),
                    SeName = _urlRecordService.GetSeName(product),
                    Sku = product.Sku,
                    ProductType = product.ProductType,
                    MarkAsNew = product.MarkAsNew &&
                        (!product.MarkAsNewStartDateTimeUtc.HasValue || product.MarkAsNewStartDateTimeUtc.Value < DateTime.UtcNow) &&
                        (!product.MarkAsNewEndDateTimeUtc.HasValue || product.MarkAsNewEndDateTimeUtc.Value > DateTime.UtcNow),
                    ProductCategories = product.ProductCategories.ToList()
            };
```

Now I have an error when I refresh second time page:

> $exception  {"Error generated for warning 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.LazyLoadOnDisposedContextWarning: An attempt was made to lazy-load navigation property 'Category' on entity type 'ProductCategoryProxy' after the associated DbContext was disposed.'. This exception can be suppressed or logged by passing event ID 'CoreEventId.LazyLoadOnDisposedContextWarning' to the 'ConfigureWarnings' method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or 'AddDbContext'."}  System.InvalidOperationException

_ProductBox.cshtml

```
<div class="category">


                @foreach (var item in Model.ProductCategories)
                {
                    @item.Category.Name
                }

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the context is disposed, the product categories cannot be lazy loaded. You can solve this by including the `ProductCategories` when loading your `Product` list. Presumably somewhere in the `ProductService`, before you call the `PrepareProductOverviewModels` method. To do this, add the `Include(navigationPropertyPath)` to the table. This forces the property to be loaded directly.

Example in `ProductService`:

```
productRepository.Table.Include("ProductCategories")
```

***Alternatively***, if you dont want to edit the default method in the `ProductService`, you could replace `product.ProductCategories.ToList()` with a custom service call.

```
ProductCategories = _productService.GetProductCategoriesForProduct(product);
```

In your `ProductService`, you should create this method like so:

```
public virtual ProductCategories GetProductCategoriesForProduct(Product product)
{
    var resultProduct = _productRepository.Table.Include("ProductCategories")
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == product.Id);
    
    if(resultProduct != null)
        return resultProduct.ProductCategories.ToList();
    else
        return null; // Product not found, return null or empty list.
}
```